# BUILD FAILED (macOS 11.4 using ruby-build 20210526) - MacBook Air (M1, 2020) - rbenv install 2.x.x

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am having issues with installing any other ruby version other than (2.7.2). Does anyone have any tips? Big Sur.

Comment: Seems after some reading. 2.7.2 and 3.0.0 are supported although other versions are not.

Answer (score 12):

I was having a problem installing ruby `2.6.7`. Run it with this CFLAG `CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.6.7` helped.

Comment: Worked for on on 2.6.5 too.

Comment: So it did on 3.1.2